# SharePoint Mapped Folder Error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I added and deploy mapped folder with .js file but all the time I get error.

[image]

Using URL:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231544.aspx

http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/06/19/include-javascript-and-css-files-in-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-web-part/

Error:

Cannot make a cache safe URL for "\template\layouts\ankietaspwp\gridrowvisible.js" , file not found. Please verify that the file exists under the layouts directory.

Do you know why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 the `layouts` folder now has a /15/ node.

Where in SharePoint 2010 your path might have been

> /_layouts/jquery.js

In SharePoint 2013 it would now be:

> /_layouts/15/jquery.js

Answer (score 2):

Check the below things...

- Check wether the file exists in the layouts folder or not. If not presented there you can put there and check.
- Set **Localizable = false**  attribute to SharePoint:ScriptLink link.

Eg:
`<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="file name" Localizable = false runat="server"/>`

Let me know if this resolved your issue?

Comment: Further to this if it the file existed in _layouts on SP2010 the filepath will need to be updated. SharePoint 2013 includes the ./15 folder in layouts so your path would now be /_layouts/15/